# Can't get ageRanges with Google API

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I can't seem to get the ageRanges property via the People API.

works:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=emailAddresses
```

does NOT work:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=ageRanges
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=ageRange
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=age_ranges
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=age_range
```

Has anyone else this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Google API works as expected.
Posting the answer here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.
I forgot to set the YEAR for my age in my Google+ account when I created it many years ago. Of course there is a 404 for age range then.
Worked flawlessly after I set the year.

Comment: I contacted someone at Google to log it as an internal bug.   I cant seam to find an issue forum for the people api.

Comment: The People API has been fixed to not return a 404 in this case but to return an empty person.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try testing using the [API exploer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.get?resourceName=people%252Fme&personFields=ageRanges&_h=8&) the request you have posted works fine.

Request

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=ageRanges&access_toke={your token}
```

response

```
{
 "resourceName": "people/11720047553267277534",
 "etag": "%EgQBNDcuGg0BAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwNIgxwMnBTbXRpYWF2RT0=",
 "ageRanges": [
  {
   "metadata": {
    "primary": true,
    "source": {
     "type": "ACCOUNT",
     "id": "11720047553267277534"
    }
   },
   "ageRange": "TWENTY_ONE_OR_OLDER"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer, appreciate it. I tried that one before to for testing the URLs above. It just hit me this morning to check if I set the year in my account. And bingo! I didn't. Works now.